# My mongodb database is taking a long period of time to query

Tags: python, mongodb, replit

So I have a big MongoDB database with like 2358 documents. Whenever I try to query it takes a long period of time and sometimes when I go to the dashboard and try to get the data it shows me this: [Image of MongoDB error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCJCC.png)

I don't know how to fix it and I need it for a project I am doing. The programming language I am using is Python and I am using the pymongo library. I don't know if it matters but I am using [repl.it](https://repl.it) to run my code

Comment: Welcome - this is a pretty small database, to be honest - would it be possible to post your queries?

Comment: @aronchick Sorry, I am a noob at MongoDB but what is a query? Is it like a document on the collections or ???

Comment: Your query is the actual string you hand to Mongo to get a bunch of responses. Based on this, it sounds like the dashboard error is not the issue here.

Comment: @aronchick Does the query really matter tho? It takes a long time for it to load for any query I put in

Comment: Try running one of your queries using the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/explain/index.html#explain) database command with the "executionStats" verbosity.  The output from that will help determine what is going on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out it was my fault. I wasn't using a query and I was just extracting all the documents from my collection at once. So the lesson is: use a query